# Travel to UK on a business visa from old company

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

I have business visa for UK processed by my old employer. I have now moved to a different company and need to visit UK again. Can I use my old visa to travel to UK ?

Comment: Is there some reason why you would not be able to use it?